# what is for(auto& x : s) in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, for-loop, tolower

Since I am new to C++, I do not know what the expression means?

and how can i co-relate this expression with C language.

```
                           #include <bits/stdc++.h>
                           using namespace std;
                           int main()
                           {

                              // string to be converted to lowercase
                              string s = "GEEKSFORGEEKS";

                              for (auto& x : s) {
                          x = tolower(x);
                              }

                                cout << s;
                                return 0;
                             }
```

Comment: Read [Range-based for-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: C++ has derived so much from C that you shouldn't treat these two related.

Comment: See [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095) and [Why using namespace std is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721).

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` Where ever you learned that, block that site in your web browser, never go to that web site again, forget you ever learned it, and get yourself a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).